# Enable/disable button depending on On Demand Resources tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle, resourcebundle, on-demand-resources

I have some buttons linked to an `IBAction` that plays a sound.

```
-(IBAction)listen {
 // play the audio
}
```

My files are organized with [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Managing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH4-SW1), and I have 3 tags:

- level1
- level2
- level3

So what I'd like to achieve is:

**if the user is on level 1, he will only be able to play files with the `level1` tag**. If he clicks on a `level2` tag audio, an alert will appear.

How can I check if a file has a specific tag?

Comment: what type of file are u referring to ?

Comment: they are mp3 files

Comment: you cannot set tag values to objects. Only UI elements can be given tags.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Managing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH4-SW1

Comment: ohh ok, the tag referred in there is different than the tag value for the UI elements. Seems the tag value is a string in your case.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, you can use conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler: method to check if the file exists in your device or not. As you are downloading the whole bundle resource but not just file, you need to provide the required tags to the sourceRequest and call that method.

Comment: all the files exist in the device. the only thing is that, depending on their tag, the user will be able to play them or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an API to access a resource's ODR tags, so you have to use some other way to map resources to access controls in your app code. Perhaps you can use `pathForResource(_:ofType:)` to inspect the path of the resource, and if it is in the directory "level2", prevent your user from accessing the resource until they are on the appropriate level?

Comment: so should I have to store my files on different folders in my project?

Comment: That would be one way to do it. I agree it would be convenient for this use case to know what tags are assigned to an asset, but that's a packaging-level detail. You wouldn't want your code to break if you stopped using ODR and started packaging all resources with the app, so it would be better to rely on a different mechanism instead of overloading the tagging mechanism in unexpected ways.

Comment: so if I have level1 folder, level2 folder, level3 folder, how should i check it?